# Percentage styling styled-components React Native issue

Tags: react-native, expo, styled-components

I'm having issues when running my expo app on iOS. I'm receiving this error on my main view, as the screenshot attached below

Which basically is because of this piece of code:

```
export const Card = styled.View`
  border-radius: 12%;

  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
`;
```

As soon as I remove the 12% (and let's say make it 12px, everything seems to be working.

I'm using styled-components `6.1.0` (which is seemingly causing the problem). Is this a known issue? How can use the % values using styled-components?

[image]

Comment: The problem with this code is not syntax but about visual effect. When you set the border-radius to 12%, it will create a border equal to the View element, but the result will not might not be visually pleasing. Using a high boundary radius like this can result in many equations that may not be as expected. If you need more cards with rounded corners, you can use a pixel value or a smaller value for the percentage. For example
export const Card = styled.View`
  border-radius: 5%; /* Use a smaller percentage */
  background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
`;

Comment: 5% and even 1% are giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass % in string. Like border-radius: '12%'